# ERROR: GETH_NEWDATE: Strange length for ODATE: 20

Tags: linux, wps

While setting up the WPS for WRF, i getting the following error while running the file **metgrid.exe**.

```
Processing domain 1 of 1
ERROR: GETH_NEWDATE: Strange length for ODATE: 20
application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0) - process 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem, and realized it was caused by either and extra or missing quote on start_date or end_date in namelist.wps.